# Can't get parameter from scope

Tags: angularjs, scope, ionic-framework, 2-way-object-databinding

Hello I just created a login page with Ionic using the `ion-nav-view` tag. That is in my index.html I have this tag which together with the `.config` enable me to change my templates with according to my specifications.

This is the body of the index.html:

```
<body ng-app="starter">

<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

This is part of the `app.js`:

```
 .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  .state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  views: {
    '': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

Here is the login.html:

```
<ion-view view-title="" name="login-view">
<ion-nav-bar ></ion-nav-bar>
      <ion-content class="padding top-space">
      <div class="item item-image padding borders">
          <img ng-src="img/welcome.png">
      </div>
      <br/>
      <br/>

      <div class="list">
         <label id="rounded" class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label"><span class="ion-email"></span> Email</span>
              <input type="email" placeholder="example@go.cm" class="button-blanche" ng-model= "loginparam.email">
         </label>
      </div>
      <div class="list">
         <label id="rounded" class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label"><span class="ion-unlocked"></span> Password</span>
              <input type="password" placeholder = "password"class="button-banche" ng-model= "loginparam.password">
         </label>
      </div>
      <button class="button button-block button-verte" ng-click="login()">Login to GoJ</button>
      <div class="padding">
        <p>Not in GoJ? <a class="green-link" ng-click="signin()">Create an Account</a></p>
        <p><a  class="green-link" href="">Forgot Password?</a></p>
      </div>
      {{loginparam}}
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

From my understanding, the index.html redirects to the login.html page when the app is launched and the controller associated to this view is the login controller. So then if I bind data on the view using the `ng-model` directive on this template it is bound to the current scope which should be that of my `LoginCtrl` but yet to no availl.

```
    .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $state, $rootScope, $ionicModal) {
    console.log("sCope  " + $scope.loginparam);//undefined
    console.log("root" + $rootScope.loginparam);//undefined
    var param = {};
    $scope.login =function(){
console.log("Checking rootscope " +$rootScope.loginparam);//undefined
console.log("Checking scope " +$scope.loginparam);//undefined
//call the login service with the login parameters from the login template

    $state.go("tab.dash");
  };
```

My `console.log($scope.loginparam)` is undefined in the LoginCtrl scope. Now I'm really confused. Can any one help me out?

Comment: I cannot get properly what you want to do. can you explain? Please explain in login page what is the use of loginParam?

Comment: In the login page I bound the loginparam to the scope of my controller using `ng-model= "loginparam.email"` I'm sure the controller for this view has to be `LoginCrtl` as defined in the `app.js` but I can't access this parameter in the controller when I use the `console.log($scope.loginparam)` so I wonder on what I missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you haven't defined `$scope.loginparam` inside your **LoginCtrl**.

Please add the following code in your **LoginCtrl**

```
$scope.loginparam = {
    email: '',
    password: ''
}
```